# What does this terminal mean? (using Next.js next/router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm creating a portfolio website with Next.js & tailwind css in ReactJs(not typescript).
I struggled with Router(next/router).
I tried to find a good sample, copy&paste, and tried to fix as much as I can. But, only one thing I just don't understand is why the words appear on my terminal everytime I refresh my webpage.

```
/
/works
/blog
/contact
```

Here is my navbar.js file and menuItems.js.
Such words didn't appear until I put menuItems.js and navbar.js.
Is this something wrong?

navbar.js

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import styles from "./layout.module.css";
import MenuItems from "./menuItems";

export const Nav = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div className={styles.nav}>
      {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
        console.log(item.url);
        return (
          <div class="flex justify-center">
            <Link href={item.url} key={index}>
              <div
                className={`p-4 cursor-pointer hover:opacity-40 ${
                  router.asPath === item.url
                    ? "bg-gray-200"
                    : ""
                }`}
              >
                <p className="text-secondary-300">{item.label}</p>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

menuItems.js

```
const MenuItems = [
    {
      label: 'Home',
      url: "/",
      active: true,
    },
    {
      label: 'Works',
      url: "/works",
      active: false,
    },
    {
      label: 'Blog',
      url: "/blog",
      active: false,
    },
   {
      label: 'Contact',
      url: "/contact",
      active: false,
    },
  ];
  
  export default MenuItems;
```

Almost all the other source codes are based on Next.js tutorial.
I would appreciate if anyone help me :)

Comment: I have answered your question, remove the console.log statement I mentioned in your code, if it solves your problem, please mark it as answered

Comment: You are right!!
I completely miss-read the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `console.log(item.url)`

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import styles from "./layout.module.css";
import MenuItems from "./menuItems";

export const Nav = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div className={styles.nav}>
      {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
        console.log(item.url); //Because of this
        return (
          <div class="flex justify-center">
            <Link href={item.url} key={index}>
              <div
                className={`p-4 cursor-pointer hover:opacity-40 ${
                  router.asPath === item.url
                    ? "bg-gray-200"
                    : ""
                }`}
              >
                <p className="text-secondary-300">{item.label}</p>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```